# Counter in set Timeout nested in set interval is summed multiple times per callback

Tags: javascript, counter, settimeout, setinterval

I have some code which is intended to update a counter that's inside of a set interval block. My intent is to have the counter updated once every time the set timeout function is called. But it seems that the callback for setTimeout is active for the entire duration of the timeout, so the counter is summed repeatedly over the 3 second timeout period, resulting in it having an end value of 8 rather than the desired value of 2.
I'm trying to understand how to implement this where the counter will be called immediately after the timeout, and only once. Unfortunately simply putting it after the function does not seem to solve this issue.

```
let count = 1;
let flag = 1;
setInterval(() => {
   if (flag == 1) {
       setTimeout(()=>{
           flag = 0;
           count++;
           }
        ,3000);
    }
},500);
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, you are triggering the setTimeout function every time the setInterval loop is running because your function will wait 3000 ms for changing `flag` to `0`. Move this change outside `setTimeout` and you're good.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a viable solution for me because I only want to set flag to 0 after the 3000ms wait. Otherwise my function the executes when flag=0 starts too early.

Comment: In that case, you have to clear the interval the moment "flag ==1" is satisfied.

Comment: Is your interval intended to be stopped fully when the timeout is done? And would it be a viable solution to track the passed time to determine when to update `flag` and `count`?

Comment: No, the interval should not be stopped after the timeout is done. Hence using clear interval would require breaking up the rest of the code into starting and stopping intervals around the timeout function. Tracking passed time would also be a viable solution (ie, set a time 3s in the future, only update count/flag when that time is reached), but the implementation is a bit more cumbersome than what I have as the accepted answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that ?

```js
let count = 1 
  , flag  = 1
  , noTimCall = true
  ;
setInterval(() =>
  {
   if (flag === 1 && noTimCall)
    {
    noTimCall = false
    setTimeout(()=>
      {
      flag = 0
      count++
      noTimCall = true
      }
      ,3000)
    }
  }
  ,500)
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why you changed it. For example, I don't  see why one would need to change `==` to `===`, or why `noTimCall` would need to be re-set to `true`. Also, once your "stopping" action is started, cancelling it would require to set `noTimCall` to `true` immediately and `flag` to `1` after the 3 second-delay, making this quite complicated. Why not choose a different approach?

Comment: @OskarGrosser  the change from `==` to `=== `is a classic, it is already explained on SO.

Comment: @OskarGrosser I done a strict reading of the **PO** question: the `setInterval` === infinite process -> it should not be stopped. `count`, `flag` are **variables** -> they can be changed by other unspecified features. He doesn't want the `setTimeOut` to interfere other than to have a 3s delay. With my solution everything stays in place: the `setTimeOut` only intervenes once when the `flag` goes to 1 and resetting it to zero. he can be reused again to further increment again the `count` when the `flag` variable goes back to 1 elsewhere. It is pure and simple logic.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through your code step by step.

- 0ms since start. `flag` is `1` ⇒ 1st timeout created.
- 500ms since start. `flag` is `1` ⇒ …
- …
- 3000ms since start. `flag` is `1` ⇒ 7th timeout created.
- 1st timeout is executed: Setting `flag` to `0`, increasing `count` to `2`.
- 3500ms since start. `flag` is `0` ⇒ Effectively nothing.
- 2nd timeout executed: …, increasing `count` to `3`.
- 4000ms since start. `flag` is `0` ⇒ …
- 3rd timeout executed: …
- …
- 6000ms since start. …
- 7th timeout executed: …, increasing `count` to `8`.

As you can see, there will be 7 timeouts created, each one increasing `count` by one, ending with `count` at `8`.

There are multiple ways to increase `count` only once after a delay:

1. Not using timeouts. We can keep track of how much time has passed manually, and increase `count` once a certain threshold (here: 3 seconds) is reached.
   Changing the variables synchronously means they will already have their new values *during* the interval-callback, unlike using timeouts where they are changed after the callback.
2. Increase `count` if and only if `flag` is changed from `1` to `0` by that timeout-callback. Further:

   1. Always create timeouts. The check inside them takes care of incrementing `count` only once, anyway.
   2. Only create one timeout. This would require a new variable.
3. Create a timeout outside of the interval-callback. However, this means we cannot check *when* to start it from within our interval, as it is created outside immediately.

## 1. Keeping track of time

To keep track of time, we need to introduce a new variable that is increased by the interval's delay at the end of our interval-callback.

Now we only need to check the passed time against a threshold (here: `3000` milliseconds), and do a certain action once that condition is met.

We can further extend our code by allowing the if-block to be en-/disabled. This can be simply accomplished using a boolean.

```js
let count = 1;
let flag = 1;

let timePassed = 0; // Tracks passed time
let isStoppingEnabled = true; // Allows toggling of the stopping if-block
// Re-starting the timer requires re-setting both variables above; see last arrow expression below

setInterval(() => {
  if (flag == 1) {
    
    // Runs once 'timePassed' reaches its threshold of 3000
    // and this if-block is "enabled" (see 'isStoppingEnabled')
    if (isStoppingEnabled && timePassed >= 3000) { 
      // Will "disable" _this_ if-block;
      // disabling outer if-block using 'flag = 0;' also works
      isStoppingEnabled = false; 
      count++;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(count);
  
  timePassed += 500; // Remember to increase 'timePassed' by the interval's delay
}, 500);

document.querySelector('#re-stop').addEventListener('click', () => {
  isStoppingEnabled = true; // Re-enable said if-block
});
document.querySelector('#re-stop-track').addEventListener('click', () => {
  isStoppingEnabled = true; // Re-enable said if-block and...
  timePassed = 0; // re-start time tracking
});
```

```css
body { /* Ignore; better styling */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 1rem 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="re-stop">Re-enable stopping</button>
<label for="re-stop">
  Since 'timePassed' will most likely be already<br>
  over its threshold of 3000, 'count' will be increased almost immediately. 
</label>
<button id="re-stop-track">Re-enable stopping and re-set time-tracker</button>
<label for="re-stop-track">
  Will re-set 'timePassed', effectively re-starting<br>
  the 3 second timer until 'count' is increased.
</label>
```

**Note:** Be wary of integer "overflows"! JavaScript won't warn about the usage of [unsafe integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)! Make sure to keep your time-tracking variable in the safe range of integers.

## 2. Using `setTimeout()`

We can create timeouts that will check whether they should execute or not using a simple if-statement.

### 2.1 Allow multiple timeouts

A simple one that will run when `flag` is set to `1` would look like this:

```js
let count = 1;
let flag = 1;

setInterval(() => {
  if (flag == 1) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (flag == 1) {
        flag = 0;
        count++;
      }
    }, 3000);
  }
  
  console.log(count);
}, 500);
```

However, that would create timeouts *as long as* the first timeout created hasn't run, since until then, the if-statement is executed, creating further timeouts. Technically, this will work just fine, but actually, it will create **unnecessary timeouts** producing **unnecessary overhead**.

### 2.2 Restricted timeout creation

We can restrict the amounts of timeouts at a time using a single boolean, since we only want to know if one was already created or not.

```js
let count = 1;
let flag = 1;

// Prefixed with "_" (underscore) because it has
// no further relevance outside of this script; should actually be private
let _isTimeoutCreated = false;

setInterval(() => {
  if (flag == 1) {
    if (!_isTimeoutCreated) { // Only create a timeout when none was created before
      _isTimeoutCreated = true; // Dis-allow creation of new timeout
      
      setTimeout(() => {
        _isTimeoutCreated = false; // Allow creation of new timeout
        flag = 0;
        count++;
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
  
  console.log(count);
}, 500);
```

## 3. Creating a timeout outside of `setInterval()`

The simplest way would be to create a single timeout after creating the interval.
Both will be created at almost the same time because timeouts and intervals are asynchronous, allowing further execution of the current call.

If they weren't, then the script would be stuck at that line, making your website unresponsive (because rendering and script-execution share the same thread).

Them being asynchronous (here meaning: "non-blocking") means, that while the interval executes, the timeout's timer will still tick down, executing after 3 seconds of your interval's creation.

The problem with this solution is, that it will only be a viable solution if you want to start the stopping process right away after starting your loop. You *can* start a new timeout from within your interval, but that would make you use either point 2.1 or point 2.2 again.

```js
let count = 1;
let flag = 1;

setInterval(() => {
  if (flag == 1) {
    console.log(count);
  }
}, 500);

setTimeout(() => {
  flag = 0;
  count++;
  console.log(count);
}, 3000);
```

## Endnote

Obviously, there are further ways to do this, like clearing the interval and creating a new one for starting/stopping it. That could be wrapped in a utility-class. Or one could use a Timer of an already existing library. Or one could find a way I couldn't think of at the top of my head.

An important last note would be to always think about the overhead you produce, especially in environments where performance matters. **But**(!) one shouldn't change his way to a different implementation only because of performance reasons, if they aren't necessary.